# How can I use an environment variable in the exec from?

Tags: dockerfile, openssh

Is there a possibility with the exec from to be able to control the path of the sshd_config via an environment variable? The service should still respond to a SIGTERM.

```
ENV SSHD_CONFIG=/var/test/sshd_config

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/sshd"]
CMD ["-D" , "-f", "$SSHD_CONFIG"]
```

As far as I've seen, openssh doesn't have an environment variable that specifies the path of sshd_config.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I also ran into this problem.

Comment: I haven't solved the actual problem. Since the container runs in kubernetes for me, you can overwrite the CMD there. That solved my problem as I know the exact values ​​when deploying.